# Eigendecomposition interpretation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a matrix $\mathbf{A}$ that has the eigendecomposition $\mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^T$. I then have a case that I would like you to help me understand:
$$
\mathbf{w} = (\mathbf{A} + \alpha \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{A}\hat{\mathbf{w}}\\
\Rightarrow \mathbf{w} = (\mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^T + \alpha \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^T\hat{\mathbf{w}} = \mathbf{Q}(\mathbf{\Lambda} + \alpha \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^T \hat{\mathbf{w}}\\
$$
I am reading in a book(https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/regularization.html, page 228) that this can be interpreted as  $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$ is being rescaled along the axes defined by the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$. Specifically, the component of $\mathbf{w}$ that is aligned with the i'th eigenvector is rescaled by a factor of $\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i + \alpha}$. Why is this true? Why is it said that we scale $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$ along the axes defined by the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{Q}$? I understand where $\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i + \alpha}$ comes from though.

I would have understood this if they said that we rescaled $\mathbf{Q}^T \hat{\mathbf{w}}$ along the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$ because the expression for $\mathbf{w}$ is a linear combination of the columns in $\mathbf{Q}$, so you would be scaling the coordinates of $\mathbf{Q}^T \hat{\mathbf{w}}$ wrt the basis defined by columns in $\mathbf{Q}$(containing eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$). But for some reason they say we scale $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$ and I do not understand why. I want it to make sense because other material would make more sense if it can be stated that $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$ on its own is being scaled.

I did some math and the result(coordinates wrt $\mathbf{Q}$) doesn't seem to be the same if you neglect $\mathbf{Q}^T$ and simply consider $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$, so I am kinda sad right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both you and the text are in agreement, and you are possibly misinterpreting the text's language.

"The component of $\hat{w}$ aligned with the $i$th eigenvector" **is** [the $i$th entry of] $Q^\top \hat{w}$; that is, $Q^\top \hat{w}$ is a vector containing the coordinates when expressing $\hat{w}$ in terms of the eigenbasis. Applying $(\lambda + \alpha I)^{-1} \Lambda$ to $Q^\top \hat{w}$ scales the $i$th coordinate by $\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i+\alpha}$. Finally, multiplying by $Q$ converts from the coordinates back to the standard basis.

More explicitly, if $\hat{w} = \sum_i c_i q_i$, then $w = \sum_i c_i \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i + \alpha} q_i$.

Comment: Thank you. But so why/how does $\mathbf{Q}$ convert it "back to the standard basis"? Why do we end up with the actual coordinates of $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$? Otherwise, I get your point

Comment: I see that $\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{Q}^T = \mathbf{I}$ but then I need to show that $\mathbf{Q} (\mathbf{\Lambda} + \alpha \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{\Lambda} 
 \mathbf{Q}^T = (\mathbf{\Lambda} + \alpha \mathbf{I})^{-1} \mathbf{\Lambda} $ right? How can I show that?

Comment: @ThatGuy Why do you want to show $Q(\Lambda + \alpha I)^{-1} \Lambda Q^\top =  (\Lambda + \alpha I)^{-1} \Lambda $? Try thinking in terms of writing $\hat{w}$ as linear combinations of columns of $Q$ like in the last sentence of my answer. $Q^\top$ converts $\hat{w}$ into the coordinates $c_i$ wrt the eigenbasis $q_i$. After applying $(\Lambda+\alpha I)^{-1} \Lambda$, you have coordinates $c_i \frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i+\alpha}$, but you still need to apply them to the eigenbasis $q_i$; this is what the final multiplication by $Q$ does.

Comment: I see. But then I cannot see why $\mathbf{Q}^T$ "undoes" the $q_i$'s in $\hat{\mathbf{w}}$? If that is true, I actually get it :o

Comment: I assume $\mathbf{Q}^T$ remove the $q_i$'s to get the coordinates wrt the eigenbasis*

Comment: @ThatGuy Try to show that $Q^\top (\sum_i c_i q_i)$ produces a vector with entries $c_i$.